To establish communication between a TypeScript React app and a Chrome extension
I have a Chrome extension. When I send a 'start' event from a React app (created by Vite TypeScript), the extension's popup should display 'activated'. Similarly, when I send a 'stop' signal, it should show 'deactivated'.
web application code
import React from 'react';

interface Message {
  action: string;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  startExtension = () => {
    // Send message to activate extension
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'activate' } as Message);
  };

  stopExtension = () => {
    // Send message to deactivate extension
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'deactivate' } as Message);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.startExtension}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={this.stopExtension}>Stop</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;`


getting this error
chrome VM8038:1 Chrome extension context not found. eval @ VM8038:1

Is this code a part of the extension and if so, how and where do you load/run it? If not, you need to use externally_connectable messaging, but note that the popup can only receive messages when it's visible.
